# Can I force .xsd to make "java.time" field instead of "java.util.date"?

Tags: java, spring, xsd

I have an xsd to make classes, with following attribute "created":

```
 <xsd:attribute name="created" use="required" type="dateTimeZone"></xsd:attribute>
```

which has custom simple type "dateTimeZone":

```
<xsd:simpleType name="dateTimeZone">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+|-]\d{2}:\d{2}"/>
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1900-01-01T00:00:00"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I want to put timezone to my java object with methods of "java.time" package, but here is the problem in generated class:

```
public void setCreated(Date value) {
        this.created = value;
    }
```

.xsd generates the "Date" field, but Date objects don't have any timezone information in them, so every time I create an instance of the class, the timezone is "00:00".

Can I force .xsd file make other type of field, tg LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime etc.?

Comment: What tool do you use to generate classes out of your XSD file?

Comment: I may be wrong (here is no one to ask now), but I think it JAXB, it presented in Maven properties and dependencies.

Comment: If you don't know, what tools you use, how could we? Your XML mapping tool is responsible for mapping XML types to Java types. So it is likely that you can customise this mapping through configuration. So the first thing you should do is to understand your tool, look into the documentation and start a Google research.